# Can I drive on this tire with sidewall damage?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage, sidewall

Hit a curb, I’m not optimistic, but take a look y’all[image]

Comment: If you could the manufacture would already have remove it to spare thousands of dollars in rubber material

Answer (score 5):

NO , do NOT continue to use that tire, the plies are exposed and will damage very rapidly either at that point, or due to moisture ingress, further away.

Put the spare on and get that one replaced, as the time of failure cannot be predicted, ie it may look ok, until you are taking a high speed corner then, suddenly you won’t be.

For your safety, and your passengers safety change it **now**, and other road users of course.