# Tire sidewall sratch - pls advise

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image]

Pls let me know if this needs replacement or repair

Thank you[image][image]

[image]

Comment: If you can peel it back and see inner sidewall threads, then replace it, otherwise it is ok.

Comment: Hi moab thank you for your comments... i put another photo.. is it ok or not?

Comment: The second photo after I zoom in on it, appears top be pretty deep and exposing the first sidewall threads, I would replace it.

Answer (score 1):

While this *looks* quite minor, it is absolutely impossible to tell what damage has been done to the cord/belt structure underneath that gash.

This question has been asked many times before, with many different pictures.

The yes/no answers are always opinion-based, and in fact always *wrong*.  The only correct answer is that it is impossible to tell without a professional evaluation - and even then you are gambling.

Advise based on a few pictures should not be given by an ethical mechanic.

**On edit (after question was edited):**

There is no *legal*  "repair" of sidewall damage in most countries.  I would be very suspicious of any shop that claims they can.  The liability is tremendous . . . any legit mechanic taking that risk clearly has little to lose.

Comment: So any answer that said the tire should be removed and not driven on is, in your opinion, incorrect ? Really...

Comment: @SolarMike  Nah, you know what I meant.  Any answer that says "YES" I can see it's perfectly safe... or "NO" byGod, that will explodulate in 40 feet are both wrong.  My point was you can't really evaluate from static pictures.  And nor should "we" embark upon that anyway.  This is not mechanical advice' this is *opinion-based* . . .

Comment: @SolarMike that last posted photo is useless.  Is it fine?  Is it okay?  Is it marginal?  Is it dog poopy??   I dunno, and me cannae tell.  It's not at my shop and it's not my wife.  Or my mistress.  Ultimately my point is that these *very frequent* questions have been asked many times before, with no real resolution.

Comment: How would you rate this one then? https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/59181/10976

Comment: @SolarMike  The question, or the answer?  Question is of the same flavor.  The answer I would rate spot-on, given your knowledge.  (But can I glue it back?). First you see cord, then you see the Lord... Perhaps there should be a "sticky"/archive where all such questions can be directed to... which should always amount to "Replace it.  Take it to a tire shop if you have any doubts."  Even then, a sharp hit that doesn't remove a lot of exterior rubber may have broken cords underneath it.  It's almost the same as "I cut myself very deeply, but I don't see any bone.  Do I need medical attention?"

Comment: Ultimately there's a huge difference between "why won't my car start?" and "is this tire safe to drive on?"  Crap advice directing posters to replace an alternator is one thing.  Crap advice to operate a vehicle with a known potentially unsafe condition is quite another.  Most of the regulars give the correct advice.  While the advice is free and under the heading of the 1st amendment, I wish there was a level of personal and professional responsibility in this forum that would obviate posting a safety judgement based on a picture or two. This always amounts to *opinion-based*.

Comment: I’m with you on the quality of the posts & responsibility.